# Set umask for a user

Tags: linux, umask

How do I make `umask` output be 22 instead of 0022?

Server1:

```
user@vxs-app01> umask
22
```

Server2

```
user@vxs-app02> umask
0022
```

Comment: I edited the question and remove unnecessary questions (like including server 1, server 2). By the way you can change umask just typing like this; `umask 22`. This only for the current session. If you need permanent then you need to put this command at bootscript like rc.local or any bootscript available based on your distribution.

Comment: What is the output of `type umask` on Server1?

Answer (score 2):

> Me:
>     I have 1¢ and I’d like to exchange it for $0.01.
>
> Currency exchange cashier:
>     Um, …, they’re the same thing.

You know that 22 and 0022 are the same number
(if they are assumed to be in the same base), right? 
If not, and I say

> 22 and 0022 are the same number
> (if they are assumed to be in the same base).

would that answer your question? 
If not,

1. You show

   ```
   user@vxs-app01$ umask
   22
   ```

   Do you ever get that? 
   Please tell us about the system where that happens.

   OK, so apparently you don’t want to tell us
   about the system(s) that you’re dealing with. 
   Then my answer is that you could be seeing any (or a combination)
   of what I discuss in the following paragraphs:

   - Server 1 could have `umask` aliased to something,
     or redefined as a shell function. 
     Type `type umask` to check.
   - The two systems could have different shells,
     or different versions of the shell.

     - `zsh` seems to display the umask with only one leading zero. 
       So that could explain `022`, but not just `22`.
     - `csh` and `tcsh` seem to display the umask with no leading zeros. 
       But `csh` and `tcsh` are radically different
       from `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, and other POSIX-friendly shells;
       if Server 1 were running `csh` or `tcsh`, you’d know.
     - Server 1 could be running a locally modified shell.
2. If you’re just showing the `22` output on Server1
   as a hypothetical example, you can get that result
   by typing `printf '%o\n' "$(umask)"`,
   which takes the raw output from `umask` (with leading zeros)
   and displays it in the default format for an octal integer
   (*without* leading zeros). 
   You can then put that into an alias or a shell function.
3. If you want the shell to remember the umask value,
   exactly as you typed it:

   ```
   $ umask 0022
   $ umask
   0022

   $ umask 22
   $ umask
   22

   $ umask 022
   $ umask
   022
   ```

   that will be harder. 
   The easier way would be to write a shell function to wrap `umask`. 
   If that’s what you want,

   - Try to figure out how to do it,
   - If you fail, edit your question to be clearer about what you want
     and what you tried, and I might devise an answer for you.

   An even harder (but more reliable) approach
   is to get the source of `bash` and modify it.

Comment: Hi , Yes, I know that both  are similar but what I want to understand why on the first server appear as 22 while second server 0022 as there is another integrated script that will depend on the output value so I want to make sure how to make them have the same output while running umask command.

Comment: Well, I believe that I’ve answered that question: you can define ```umask``` to be an alias or a shell function — although it might be tricky to get that to affect a script without modifying the script.  Or you could modify the shell. But the fact that the two servers are behaving differently is unusual, especially if they are running the same version of the same operating system, so I’m thinking that your best course of action is to figure out ***why*** they’re different, and then *fix that.*